# Testing Semantic-UI Dropdown: How to wait for it to be populated?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, semantic-ui-react, react-testing-library

I've successfully implemented the Semantic-UI Dropdown to display a list of companies.  Now I'm trying to build Jest / React Testing Library tests for it.  To accomplish this, I built this Mock Request:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  request.get = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    companies: [
      {"company_id": 1, "company_name": "ABC"},
      {"company_id": 2, "company_name": "DEF"}
    ]
  }));
});
```

Based on a console.log I added to my component code, this appears to work as expected.

Here's an abridged example of my instance of this element:

```
<div id="companyId" data-testid="companies-dropdown" role="combobox">
  <input autocomplete="companyId" class="search" type="text">
  <div class="default text" "role="alert">Ex. ABC Corp</div>
  <div role="listbox">
    <div role="option"><span class="text">ABC</span></div>
    <div role="option"><span class="text">DEF</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where I'm struggling is to correctly wait in my test for the Dropdown to get populated:

```
it('Should populate the Search and Select Company dropdown with 2 companies', async () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText, getByRole } = displayModal();
  const listBox = await waitForElement(() => getByRole('listbox'));
});
```

The error message is: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listbox"

I also tried this alternate approach but got the same error message:

```
const listBox = await waitForElement(() => within(getByTestId('companies-dropdown')).getByRole('listbox'));
```

Might anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I happened to see this while I was searching something else. But in your case, you are using wrong role. I achieved my use case with the following:

- First focus the input element of the div to open dropdown. I use the input element:

  - `userEvent.click(getByLabelText('Company'))`
  - The above can be replaced by using `data-testid` or with role '`combobox`'
- Get all the roles for the select options:

  - `getAllByRole('option')`

`const companyAbc = getAllByRole('option').find(ele => ele.textContent === 'ABC') userEvent.click(companyAbc); // verify your onChange event`

In your async case:

`const companyAbc = await findAllByRole('option').find(ele => ele.textContent === 'ABC') userEvent.click(companyAbc); // verify your onChange event`

SemanticReact also has `onSearchChange` event that you can use to trigger for every input search if that's the use case.