# React Bootstrap Modal: onEntered event doesn't fire in Jest test environment

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-bootstrap

This is a follow-up to a previous post of mine: [Testing Semantic-UI Dropdown: How to wait for it to be populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024913/testing-semantic-ui-dropdown-how-to-wait-for-it-to-be-populated)

My React Bootstrap Modal is defined like this:

```
<Modal
  backdrop={'static'}
  size='lg'
  show={true}
  centered={true}
  onHide={handleCancelClick}
  onEntered={e => setIsLoaded(true)}
  data-testid='add-vehicles-modal'
>
```

The `onEntered` event works perfectly in production, and as you can see, sets `isLoaded = true`, which in turn causes a bunch of companies to be fetched from an API to populate my dropdown list.

[Trigger modal shown for React Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836812/trigger-modal-shown-for-react-bootstrap)

However, I've discovered that `onEntered` isn't triggered in the Jest test environment, which is why the companies are never loaded, when tests are expecting them to be.

I wonder if anyone has any suggested workarounds?

Comment: Get same behavior in Overlay